# Stopwatch Lap Comparison

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created a stopwatch web app with HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JS. It counts and stops just fine, with a lap function that prints a separate lap timer running under the main timer.

Now, my issue comes up when I'm trying to get the highest and lowest lap times. I am able to get those values to a certain degree but it's not completely accurate in some time cases. For instance, when you lap 00:02:03 and 00:00:42 respectively, my code picks the first time as the lowest lap time because '03 is lower than '42. The same situation happens when selecting the highest lap.

I'm trying to store the indexes of specific lap times to then proceed to check for the lowest millisecond, in a bigger amount of lap times than just two for example. I have a function for that but it returns only one index number when there are meant to be more.

```
// code to select minimum lap so far
    const minimumLap = {
    minimumLapsecond: function() { return lapsecarray.reduce(
        (min, currentValue) => Math.min(min, currentValue),
        lapsecarray[0]
      )},
      minimumLapmillisecond: function(){ return lapmilliarray.reduce(
        (min, currentValue) => Math.min(min, currentValue),
        lapmilliarray[0]
      )},
}
lapsecarray.reverse();
lapmilliarray.reverse();

function lapComparison() {
  let lapRow = lapTableBody.querySelectorAll("tr");
  lapRow.forEach((tr) => tr.classList.remove("min"));
  //minimum lap
  if (countInArray(lapsecarray)(minimumLap) === 1) {
      miniLapindex = lapsecarray.indexOf(minimumLap);
      console.log(miniLapindex);
      lapRow.item(minLapIndex).classList.add("min");
    }
    else if (countInArray(lapsecarray)(minimumLapsecond()) > 1) {
       minLapIndex = lapmilliarray.indexOf(minimumLapmillisecond());
      lapRow.item(minLapIndex).classList.add("min");
    }

// counting for multiple seconds or milliseconds in the array to determine which lap time to search
const countInArray = (array) => (value) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
// the indexing function that doesn't work as expected 

function indexesOf(array) {
  let indexes = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(i, 0) === value) {
        indexes.push(i);
      }
  }
  return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with your code, I have an example idea that you could implement.

First, I strip the colons from the laps. Then I just use Math.min and Math.max to find the min/max from the array.

It might seem like a strange workaround, but without the colons, they just become normal numbers.

```js
laps = ["00:02:03","00:00:42"]; //an array of saved lap times
lap_times = {}; //an empty object that will hold the Numerical Lap time as a key and the string version as the value ie: lap_times[42] = "00:00:42" that way we can grab the original time after determining min/max

laps = laps.map(function(lapTime){//loops through the array and returns a modified value back in each values place
   lap = Number(lapTime.replace(/:/g,"")); //replaces the colons and converts to a Number
   lap_times[lap] = lapTime //sets the converted time as the key and original time as the value
   return lap;
});


/* ... is called spread/rest syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Without using lap_times[], min/max would return the numerical representation of the time. So by adding it, it will pull back the previously created full string value

*/

slowest = lap_times[Math.max(...laps)];
fastest = lap_times[Math.min(...laps)];
console.log("slowest", slowest,"fastest" , fastest)
```

Comment:  oh wow, d'you know I've been battling with this since yesterday and I didn't think of converting the lap string into numbers. Well, I'm fairly new to js, I just started in March this year. So I almost have no idea what you typed but it looks like it works  . I get the overall idea so hopefully, I'll be able to find something simpler to use or your trick. @imvain2

Comment: @MorganJay, I updated my answer to include some clarification what everything is and why its being used.

Comment: ah yes thank you. I'm having some trouble getting the overall min/max times tho... Where the lap times are equal. Either the max or the min. @imvain2

Comment: my function to count how many equal minimum laps are present in the array doesn't seem to work, it's in my original question. I need to tweak it to return the indexes of the two or more minimum times so as to determine where to search for the overall minimum time. Here's a link to the project mjstopwatch.netlify.app

Comment: @MorganJay, I get the impression that you are over complicating the project. Using my code, you will get the max and min laps. You don't need to mess with any indexes. After each lap finishes, just run my code and you will get the max and min laps.

Comment: yeah your code works fine. I'm not overcomplicating things tho I'm just trying to mimic the stopwatch on my phone...
in a case where you have two identical min laps. what do you do.... that is what I'm trying to achieve now
did you check the link I sent?

Comment: your code even shows an error now but I handled it and it does it job. @imvain2
```
mapLaps: ()=> {
    GetLapComparison.laps = GetLapComparison.laps.map((lapTime) =>{
      // try {
        lap = Number(lapTime.replace(/:/g, ""));
      // } catch (error) {}
      GetLapComparison.lap_times[lap] = lapTime;
      return lap;
    });
```
logs Uncaught TypeError: lapTime.replace is not a function
    at stopwatch.js:160
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.mapLaps (stopwatch.js:158)
    at Object.getMinimumLap (stopwatch.js:170)